# Python or django reporting tools not how to generate pdf, like asp.net crystal report

Tags: python

Python or django reporting tools not how to generate pdf, like asp.net crystal report

Comment: I use pod: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943597/using-variable-images-with-django-webodt

Answer (score 2):

1. Look at [Geraldo Reports](http://www.geraldoreports.org/docs/index.html).
2. [Python Report](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) Lab is a level below in the stack but is very, very easy to roll your own report classes based in this toolkit.
3. If you love Crystal, you may like to look at [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/) and the wonderful iReport. Once defined in iReport, you can render your reports calling Jasper classes from Jython.